# What extra roles have you used with Werewolves?

Tags: house-rules, werewolf

The standard game Werewolf, has just a few roles: Citizen, Werewolf, Witch, Cupid, Hunter, Seer, Thief.  I know there are lots of other roles created.

Which roles do you use and what is the impact.

## Default Roles

- **Citizen**, cast a vote during the day.
- **Wolf**, *citizen*, knows other *wolves*, chose each night a victim to eliminate from the game.
- **Witch**, has two potions, each night the witch knows the victim of the *wolves*. She has one potion to save a victim and one to poison another player (hopefully a werewolf).
- **Cupid**, choses two players the first night. These are the lovers. The lovers know each other and they have to survive together. If one dies the other dies too. If a *werewolf* and a *citizen* are lovers, they have to kill the others to win.
- **Hunter**, if the hunter dies, he choses another player to die with him.
- **Seer**, the seer can query a players role each night.

## Other roles

- **Executer**, during the voting, the executer can present himself and execute another player. Voting continues afterwards. The executer can execute only once.
- **Priest**, if the votes are counted, the priest can present himself and use holy water on the victim. If it is a *werewolf* or the *witch* the victim dies, else the victim lives. Priests can have one or more bottles of holy water.
- **Guardian Angel**, each night a guardian angel can protect a player. This player cannot be eaten by the *werewolves*. The guardian angel cannot protect himself.
- **Alpha Werewolf **, this *werewolf*, can select another player to become a werewolf. This can happen only once.
- **Soul mates**, soul mates are *citizens* that know each other. They can't become werewolves, if the *Alpha werewolf* tries to convert a soul mate, the attempt is failed.

Comment: I would include only the Citizens (Villagers), Wolves, and Seer in the "default roles". All of the others are extras, at least in the original Werewolf rules http://eblong.com/zarf/werewolf.html. Even the Seer could be considered extra; the original Mafia had just two roles, the Mafia and the Citizens: http://web.archive.org/web/19990302082118/http://members.theglobe.com/mafia_rules/.

Comment: I agree with Brian. If this was a wiki article, or I could edit it, I would.
Also, it would probably improve the effect of the answer rankings if your moved all of your "Other Roles" into answers that could be voted on.

Comment: I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based; it is social fun, and a "I have used X, what have you used?" question. It's a survey for new roles, regardless of quality, and not a problem to solve.

Comment: @doppelgreener since when are house rules opinion based? The answers to this question are plural, but finite, and are valuable to future visitors. I don't think this question should be closed in its current form.

Comment: @freekvd This question matches [multiple types of question to avoid asking](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): it's "I use X, what do you use?", every answer is equally valid, there isn't a concrete problem to solve, it's open ended. It's a list question, [which do not function in the Stack Exchange format](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/152515). Valuable, certainly, but SE has its functional niche, and we don't try to handle everything that might be valuable. This can be gathered on other sites that better fit it, like Reddit. (SE isn't trying to be a one-stop shop.)

Comment: @doppelgreener Yikes, you're absolutely right. What about a finite list of 'official' characters from werewolf games by various publishers?

Comment: @freekvd It'd have to be a reasonably different sort of question. "What do you use and what is the impact?" is not a problem. Whatever question it is should actually contain a problem to which there is an answer. (And for the record, should be new, not an edit to this question.)

Answer (score 7):

I've played with several of the roles invented by [The Graduate Mafia Brotherhood of Princeton University](http://fringe.davesource.com/Fringe/Entertainment/Games/Indoors/Mafia/), but the most memorable was the [Kingmaker](http://fringe.davesource.com/Fringe/Entertainment/Games/Indoors/Mafia/v30.htm):

> A despotic regime has siezed power, usurping democracy. Each turn, there will be a King or Queen who has the sole power to decide who will be lynched. Open debate is allowed, but the day ends as soon as the King/Queen makes his/her choice.
>
> The Kingmaker is a civilian, who, each night, names a King/Queen for the following round. The Kingmaker cannot choose himself, and he cannot choose the same person for two consecutive rounds. The Kingmaker must choose someone.

One game in particular, the Kingmaker's pleas of "Don't bite the hand that feeds you" went entirely unheeded.  We played the rest of that game democratically.

I also noticed that with too many roles in use, moderation can get ridiculously hard.

Comment: I see a deadlock. If there are two people left, the kingmaker and the previous king/queen, there can be no king but there must be a king.

Comment: By that point, the game is already over anyway, so the winning condition applies.  If the previous king/queen is mafia or a werewolf, he/she wins.

Answer (score 7):

I like the Sheriff. This is an elected position. On the first day, before any lynchings, there is a public debate and vote to decide the Sheriff. The Sheriff then appoints a deputy who will take over if/when they are killed.

The Sheriff has two votes when it comes to lynching.

Comment: Do you play Sherrif-ful games with an even number of players?

Comment: Yeah, it's a great way to resolve ties.

Comment: Just wanted to add/clarify that of course there can still be a tie when playing with a Sheriff, it's just that his choice prevails in such situations. (Imagine him having two and a half votes rather than exactly 2.0.)

Comment: Right, we used to have a Sheriff chosen by the moderator / game leader / dungeon master, and no deputy. We also called him Mayor.

Answer (score 5):

We usually play it with:

- the **Immortal** - if wolves choose to kill him, he doesn't die (he still can be lynched)
- the **Whore** - each night she must choose a person to lie with: she dies if she chose a wolf, otherwise nothing happens (henceforth she knows that that person is not a wolf)

Mind that using the whore two people can die in a single night, giving an advantage to the wolves; usually this outweighs the whore ability of sometimes knowing that someone is not a wolf, especially if she's unlucky enough to choose a wolf on the first night.

Comment: Well, the "whore" is not precisely a politically correct denomination, but it gives the idea clearly... ;)

Comment: Do you have many female players?

Comment: Usually a little less then half of the players are female, why?

Answer (score 5):

These are mine. I am usually always the moderator, so I pick a few of these classes at random for game. It'd be ridiculous to use all of them at once. Though I have tried it for fun once. I number the cards for certain reasons. (You'll see in the roles) It also allows me to say their number instead of saying their role, unless they are the "Always in the game" roles, IE. Werewolves, Seer. You can chose which ones these are. That way players have to actually think on what the roles are. So for instance: Number three, wake up. What will you do? Me and my friends have played for a very long time, so we always know what to do.

**Villager** Normal town role, cannot do anything but vote at day.

**Werewolf** The werewolves have to kill everyone and be the last men standing. They are allowed to decide at night who to kill. They have a maximum of 1 minute, and can end their conversation short if they please.

**Neighborhood Watch** At night, the NHW can see everything, who visited who. This can only be done once.

**Veteran**  At night, can go on alert and kill whoever visits them.

**Mayor:** Starts as a normal villager, but has the choice to reveal. Flipping his card and now his votes count as 3. You can pretend to be Mayor, but if you're not. You CANNOT flip your card.

**Tanner** The tanner was loved by all. But after drugs, his nain goal is to be lynched. Once he is lynched, he picks a number from X-Y (Depending on how many numbers are on the cards/how many cards there are) once he picks, the person with that number turns over their card at day, and has killed them self. If he is killed from some other form besides lynch, he fails.

**Werewolf Hunter** At night, the WH as 3 arrows. She can shoot whoever she wants, but if she runs out of arrows, she cannot kill anymore. This is a vigilante Town Role.

**Vampire** There is only one vampire. Every night, the vampire kills someone. The vampire is it's own team. It wins once it is the only one alive.

**Seer** The Seer can choose one person at night. If it is a killing role, he gets a thumbs down. If a villager, he gets a sideways hand, or a fist. If it is a special town role then he gets a thumbs up. Seer goes at the very end of the night. Important for witch.

**Little Girl** A worse version of the Seer. Every night she can choose someone to visit. However if she chooses a Killing Role, she dies. This includes WH. Once she inspects a Seer however, the current Seer dies. And the LG becomes a Sheriff. If the LG inspects the victim of a Werewolf, the LG and the victim both die.

**Sheriff** The sheriff can decide at night when woken up, to either have detailed descriptions of their "victims", or for when he inspects someone, to have the same rules as Seer, but the results are announced by the Moderator.

**Hero** The hero can choose one person to protect at night, but instead of the victim dying, the Hero and the attacker both die. This applies to ALL killing classes.

**Mage** The Mage at night, chooses one person to stun for the entire night, getting in the way of whatever he was about to do. ie. The werewolf attacks John, but is stunned by a mage. Thus it never happens. Whenever the Mage wants, he can decide to become a Magician, or a Witch.

**Magician** The Magician has a bunny and a magic stick. The bunny can distract (stun) someone, but only has one use. The Magic Stick protects whoever he targets, like a medic.

**Witch** Has 3 potions, Poison, and Stun. The stuns whoever he targets. Poison kills whoever he visits and himself. The witch can also mind control one person and make him do his action on another person. If a villager, then nothing happens. If a seer, then (and this is my favorite part) the Seer gets the results of the Witch's target, not the Seer's target. The witch does not see the results. The witch must go first, so that there are no mix ups for the other player's role results.

**Executioner** The executioner's goal is to get his target lynched. His target is a random player, and can even be a werewolf. The moderator, on the first night, tells the Executioner to wake up. The moderator then points (The moderator must be very specific for no mixups) to the target. The executioner's main goal is to get him lynched. If the target is killed at night, the executioner becomes a tanner.

**Cupid** Cupid goes second on night one, and decides who to people are to become lovers. The two people who are chosen are tapped by the moderator. The two open their eyes and look at eachother.  These choices can be influenced by a Witch. If the witch chooses cupid to "Lover" someone else, Cupid will turn into a lover. Once Cupid dies, he can choose one person to kill themselves, if he wishes, he can abstain. Cupid cannot choose someone to die if he dies from Burst. Cupid wins from staying alive, and having the Lovers survive. If the lovers die, Cupid turns to stone. Once Cupid turns to stone, he has two choices. For the Werewolves to win, or for the villagers to win. He cannot work with the Werewolves in their conversation, or speak during the lynch. However at one point during the night, every night. He will be asked to shatter. Shattering will let him talk for one day, and die at night. He can lie about the Werewolves, or rat out the Werewolves. The Moderator will ask which side Cupid is on, a thumbs up is town. A thumbs down is Werewolf.

**Lover** Every night, the lovers wake up and without words, use their hands, arms, face expressions to make out a plan for 1 minute. If the lovers decide to, they can end this discussion short. Cupid is involved in this chat. Cupid has an over all decision on how the lovers will act. However if both Lovers agree, they can make Cupid burst. (Die) If cupid dies, nothing happens to the Lovers. Whoever kills the lovers, gets one extra life once they die. Making Lover and Cupid the hardest in the game. Once one lover dies, they both die. The lovers must stay alive until the end of the game.

Answer (score 3):

Medic - Each night he/she selects someone that will not die that night. (Hopefully that someone is not himself). Everyone knows who is the Medic, but he can be a Werewolf.

Comment: Why wouldn't the werewolves finish him off the first night if everyone knows who he is?

Comment: Yes they can, but he can select himself to not die thus preventing a death that night.

Comment: I played this rule before but the role was called the 'Friendly Hitch-hiker'

Comment: If the medic selects the medic each night, he can't be killed by a werewolf. So I assume he can't chose the same person twice in a row.

Comment: Sounds like a much lamer version of the **Gurardian Angel** above.

Answer (score 0):

A couple roles we use:

**Vigilante** - A villager who picks someone they think is a werewolf to kill each night.  Can't be a werewolf.  Can choose not to kill.

**Little Girl** - Can peek out during the werewolf's turn at night and see who they are.  If she is spotted by the wolves, she dies.

**Magician** - Similar to the Seer, but where a seer can only query a player's role and get either is/is not a wolf, the magician can get role information about the player as well (for major roles we use; seer, healer, werewolf or villager, can be expanded with enough hand signs!)

**Cupid** - In our version of cupid, the star-crossed lovers don't know each other.

Comment: "If she is spotted by the wolves, she dies." WTFLOL, that's total nonsense.

Comment: what's nonsense about it?  The wolves have to see her peeking; if they can point her out, she dies.

Comment: That's a totally flawed rule, that cannot be enforced without risking ruining the whole game. It's absolutely opposite to the spirit of the original game where no "dexterity" is involved and where there can't be any unclear issue: either something happens or it doesn't.

Comment: I disagree completely. There is no dexterity involved in opening or closing your eyes; since that is a required part of the game already. If the wolves spot the LG, they indicate that to the moderator, and the moderator indicates whether or not they are correct. Furthermore, this is a role we've used successfully for over two years.

Comment: One tactic sometimes used is for the Little Girl to just pretend to be a werewolf. That way she doesn't look suspicious and the werewolves won't ''figure'' it out.

Comment: So if she survives the first night, she can point out all wolves and end the game immediately...?

Answer (score 0):

**The scapegoat** - If there is a tied vote and the scapegoat is still alive they are lynched.

Answer (score 0):

I invented the ressurector who can bring one person and one random card back to life every other round, but in my experience the ressurector always happens to die first which is weird.

You could also play where everyone has jobs as a cover during the day. There's a journalist who makes up a story about how everyone died, a gossiped who tells lies and blames others for the killing, and other jobs.

I play without villagers because when you play like that it can get boring sometimes for them. I use all special characters

Answer (score -1):

Our moderator has started with the first night time kill being the previous sheriff. Then daytime. The moderator states the sheriff was killed and asks for any volunteers to take the badge (who gets two votes in ties). Then the game officially begins with a daytime lynching.